# In MYSQL Write Case statement and call a procedure in the when clause

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, case

I have a simple procedure that i give an int to and it returns me a 1 or 0.
so for example if i write:
call `myProcedure`() then i get a 1 or 0

Now i have a list of integers.  I want to run that procedure on each integer in this list.

I wrote:

```
select case when `myProcedure`(1315)=1 then 1 else 1315 end;
```

this wont compile.

i also tried:

```
select case when call `myProcedure`(1315)=1 then 1 else 1315 end;

call case when `myProcedure`(1315)=1 then 1 else 1315 end;

select case when `myProcedure`(1315)=true then 1 else 1315 end;
```

and a few others and they all failed.

```
call `myProcedure`(1315); --returns a 1.
```

I was told by some people here that you cant call stored procedures from case statements.  that might be what is the problem.  because it works when i do:

```
select case when 1>0 then 1 else 0 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

to use it in this context, you would have to define it as a stored function. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function.html